# Need help adding controlled loops in my python code

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I am doing this for a school project, but I haven't been able to figure out how to do this last part and get it to work properly. This is quite simple so I would appreciate any quick help.

I am coding a system that randomly generates a three-digit code, and the user has to guess what it is. They have unlimited tries, and I figured out how to get it to loop, but it won't stop looping when they guess the code right. How do I do this?

Current Code (With Error):

```
import random
NUMBERS1 = ("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9")
NUMBERS2 = ("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9")
NUMBERS3 = ("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9")
code = random.choice(NUMBERS1) + random.choice(NUMBERS2) + random.choice(NUMBERS3)
print(code)
while True:
  codeguess = input('Guess the 3 Digit Code: ')
  if codeguess == (code):
    print('Good Job! The Code was ' + code)
  else:
    print('Wrong! Try Again!')
while False:
  print('Eyyyyy')
```

Comment: Use `break` to get out of a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a break statement in the if condition in order to break the loop when the user enters correct code, just like this:

```
import random
NUMBERS1 = ("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9")
NUMBERS2 = ("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9")
NUMBERS3 = ("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9")
code = random.choice(NUMBERS1) + random.choice(NUMBERS2) + random.choice(NUMBERS3)
print(code)
while True:
  codeguess = input('Guess the 3 Digit Code: ')
  if codeguess == (code):
    print('Good Job! The Code was ' + code)
    break
  else:
    print('Wrong! Try Again!')
```

And you don't need the `while False:` loop. That is a separate infinite loop and will start only after the first while loop ends.

Answer (score 1):

Use `break` statement when the correct code is guessed.

```
while True:
  codeguess = input('Guess the 3 Digit Code: ')
  if codeguess == (code):
    print('Good Job! The Code was ' + code)
    break
  else:
    print('Wrong! Try Again!')
```

Answer (score 1):

use:

```html
import random
NUMBERS1 = ("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9")
NUMBERS2 = ("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9")
NUMBERS3 = ("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9")
code = random.choice(NUMBERS1) + random.choice(NUMBERS2) + random.choice(NUMBERS3)
print(code)
while True:
  codeguess = input('Guess the 3 Digit Code: ')
  if codeguess == (code):
    print('Good Job! The Code was ' + code)
    break
  else:
    print('Wrong! Try Again!')
```

Answer (score 0):

Once the codeguess is equal to code, inside that if statement you need to assign a variable to cause the while loop to exit. The second while loop is not needed. I have put my solution below:

```
import random
NUMBERS1 = ("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9")
NUMBERS2 = ("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9")
NUMBERS3 = ("0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9")
code = random.choice(NUMBERS1) + random.choice(NUMBERS2) + random.choice(NUMBERS3)
print(code)
# add this line
guessright = False
# change this while condition
while not guessright:
  codeguess = input('Guess the 3 Digit Code: ')
  if codeguess == (code):
    print('Good Job! The Code was ' + code)
    #add this to exit loop
    guessright = True
  else:
    print('Wrong! Try Again!')
# remove this code
# while False:
#   print('Eyyyyy')
```